# Framerate smoothing in swift SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Currently, I’m trying to create a game in swift’s SpriteKit, and I’m trying to give it a smoother framerate than it has currently. Right now, whenever I, say, press a button, the framerate suddenly jumps to a much lower value, causing the player sprite (whose movement is based on a value multiplied by a deltaTime value) to suddenly jump forward. Is there any way to smooth the framerate such that the changes in framerate aren’t so sudden and drastic?

Comment: Is this in the simulator or on a real device? When you press the button, how much extra work are you doing in the code?

Comment: It’s in the simulator. Since I’m not very experienced with swift, I may be doing some unnecessary work when I press the button. The game more-or-less retains 55-to-60 frames per second, but I’m just looking to prevent these sudden jumps in framerate.

Comment: That explains it - all bets are off regrading performance when running in the simulator. All it’s good for is checking functionality, although ‘draw count’ display can be useful and it can also show if a change to your code has made a big difference to frame rate.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code running in the simulator isn't a good test of the graphics performance of a Sprite-Kit (or Scene Kit) application.

This is because SK will, in order to perform certain graphics effects, utilise calls to the specific graphics hardware available in an iOS device whereas in the simulator, these calls will need to be emulated in software by the host machine, causing a reduction in graphics performance (some operations will be affected a lot, other less so), even if the underlying graphics card in the host machine is nominally more powerful that the one in the iOS device.

Simulator testing is good for testing functionality, and it can give an indication of performance. For example, an application that was running OK in the simulator suddenly starts performing poorly after a change. Checking the displayed 'draw count' shows that the number of 'draws' required to render the scene has increased, possibly causing the slowdown. Or conversely, a change may lead to an increase in performance and a reduction in draw count.

However, the only way to be sure is to test the application of a real device.